# ActiveMQ configuration with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, activemq-classic

I use ActiveMQ as Embedded with Spring Boot.
It seems the Broker is created trough an ActiveMQConnectionFactory.
I understand that the way to configure the broker is to set parameters in the query with broker. as described here : http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-embed-a-broker-inside-a-connection.html

I would like to setup some features about the DLQ, so it's in the destinationPolicy attribute, but the attribute type is not a simple type but a complex type, how can I write the query parameter to disable DLQ, please ?

Answer (score 4):

Complementing @Petter and @April answers, below the same solutions but with more complete samples:

[1. Petter solution, import activemq.xml at connnection factory url](https://github.com/mageddo/gs-messaging-jms/blob/activemq-embedded-config-2/src/test/java/com/mageddo/jms/QueueTest.java)

**build.gradle**

```
ext {
    springBootVersion = "1.5.3.RELEASE"
    activeMQVersion = "5.14.5"
}

dependencies {

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-activemq:${springBootVersion}")
    compile("org.apache.activemq:activemq-broker:${activeMQVersion}")

    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:${springBootVersion}")
    testCompile group: 'org.apache.activemq', name: 'activemq-spring', version: "${activeMQVersion}"
    testCompile("junit:junit:4.12")

}
```

**src/main/resources/activemq.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core
                http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core-5.4.0.xsd
        ">
    <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="broker1" persistent="false" >
        <transportConnectors>
            <transportConnector name="vm" uri="vm://broker1"/>
        </transportConnectors>
    </broker>
</beans>
```

**Config.java**

```
@EnableJms
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
public class Config {}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.activemq.broker-url=vm://broker1?brokerConfig=xbean:activemq.xml
```

[2. April solution, import activemq.xml at Spring Configuration](https://github.com/mageddo/gs-messaging-jms/blob/activemq-embedded-config/src/test/java/com/mageddo/jms/QueueTest.java)

Just remove `application.properties` then add `@ImportResource("classpath:activemq.xml")` entry to **Config.java**

**Config.java**

```
@EnableJms
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:activemq.xml")
public class Config {}
```

Answer (score 3):

Good question. The properties on the vm-transport for auto-broker creation are great, but only up to a point which I think you have hit.

My suggestion is that you define the broker configuration as you normally would have done in XML and then just refer to this xml in the URI. Destination policies are indeed a complex structure and I don't see how it would be a good idea to define them with simple query params even if it was possible.

```
vm://localhost?brokerConfig=xbean:activemq.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and solved it by using a spring configuration file. In my case, I wanted to configure my broker to persist.

I added the needed libs in my pom: including activemq-broker, activemq-spring, spring-jms (and in my case, activemq-leveldb-store).

My spring xml file looked like this:

```
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

 <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="xyz">
      <persistenceAdapter>
        <levelDB directory="activemq-data"/>
      </persistenceAdapter>

    <transportConnectors>
      <transportConnector uri="vm:localhost?persistent=true" />
    </transportConnectors>

  </broker>
</beans>
```

And I registered the spring file in one of my configuration classes:

```
@ImportResource("activemq-spring.xml")
```

That did the job.

I tried the xbeans solution first, but I got stuck because I was missing some xbeans classes, and I didn't know if it was a version thing or what. I'm using activemq 5.12.1