# I want configure my own BrokerURI in ActiveMQ e.g http://localhost:7001

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic, jms-topic

HI All I am new to this Topic called JMS. So in our project we have used ActiveMQ for JMS so right now in activemq.xml file is having cofiguration for tcp:localhost:61616 url. So we have start this server double click on means activemq.bat file then this server starts and we can make Connection with ActiveMQ.

So my question if my server is e.g. http://localhost:7001, and I want configure ActiveMQ for this server then what I need to do.(or AciveMQ will need separate server ?)

Please forgive if anything wrong in Question as I am new to this topic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure embedded ActiveMQ Broker URL with Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38750843/how-to-configure-embedded-activemq-broker-url-with-spring-boot)

Comment: **So my question if my server is e.g. http://localhost:7001, and I want configure ActiveMQ for this server then what I need to do.(or AciveMQ will need separate server ?)** 
not easy to understand what you need exactly, if you want to change the transport port, you can do it in activemq.xml as below and restart the broker.
`<transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:7001?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>`
take a look here 
http://activemq.apache.org/configuring-transports.html